# Binomial Min-Heap Priority Queue with generic types

Tags: java, generics, heap, pq

I am currently implementing Binomial Min-Heap Priority Queue with generic types.

I have given the following binomialminheap.java:

```
class BinomialMinHeap <K extends Comparable<? super K>, P>
{

    public static class Entry <K, P> {
        private P priority;
        private K key;
        private Node<P, K> node;

        private Entry (K k, P p)
        {
            priority = p;
            key= k;
        }

        public P priority () { return priority; }
        public K key() { return key; }
    }

    private static class Node <K, P> {

        private Entry<K, P> entry;

        private Node<K, P> parent;
    .
        private Node<K, P> child;

        private Node<K, P> sibling;

        private int degree;

        private Node (Entry<K, P> e)
        {
            entry = e;
            e.node = this;
        }

        private P priority ()
        {
            return entry.priority;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I have the generic types P and K. The problem here is, I have no idea how to implement the generics types into my binary heap. How do "Entry", "Node" and "BinomialHeap" work together?

I began with following constructor and few methods:

```
    private Node<P,D> Nodes;
    private int size;

    public BinomialMinHeap()
    {
        Nodes = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty ()
    {
        return Nodes == null;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }
```

I have to add following methods:

```
boolean contains (Entry<K, P> e)
Entry<K, P> insert (K k, P p)
boolean changePriority (Entry<K, P> e, P p)
Entry<K, P> minimum ()
Entry<K, P> extractMinimum ()
boolean remove (Entry<K, P> e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you first go through some generic algorithm implementations, then you will get an idea about the implementation of generic algorithms. For example following are some generic sorting algorithms.

[Heap Sort](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/heap-sort-java.html)

[Insertion Sort](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/insertion-sort-java.html)

[Selection Sort](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/selection-sort-java.html)

[Merge Sort](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/merge-sort-java.html)

[Quick Sort](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/quick-sort-java.html)